# Dishwasher Leaked. Next steps?

Tags: water, leak, floor, dishwasher, damage

Found water at the base of the dishwasher. No idea how long we’ve had this issue, as we noticed water UNDER our rug.

One possible coincidence is that a water company found moisture in our drywall in the room underneath the dishwasher. We figured it was due to bad grading (the wall is against the ground outside). I also want to note that our kitchen floor, in general has always been wavy and creaky since we moved in 2 years ago, allegedly due to a bad subfloor.

How should we proceed at this point? Merely fix the dishwasher? Have someone come out to assess the damages? Contact our insurance asap? Like I said, the issues above COULD be due to the dishwasher leak, or it could be a new leak that we just noticed.

Any tips on where we should start or who to contact would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most dishwashers are held in place by two screws in the top front (undercounter). You can unscrew those, also the two screws in the bottom kick-plate to remove that piece.

Then pull the dishwasher out slowly, avoiding pinching the water, drain or electrical cord. If concerned, put a sheet of corrugated cardboard to protect the floor.

Get it level on your kitchen floor, newspaper underneath is a good trick, but cardboard too. You should be able to start a wash with everything still connected and see if there is a physical leak.

Be careful if you open the door as the dishwasher will tip forward.

You will also be able to look where the water damage is.
Four screws, easy troubleshooting to see if it is the actual dishwasher leaking.

That could help inform you on what steps to take for home warranty or home insurance.

Answer (score 0):

First I would contact the insurance company, this sounds like it could get expensive. The second thing I would do is to try to find the source of the leak. A trick I have used for many years is get newspaper and spread it under the unit. Then run it and check the paper. If it is leaking it will give you a clue as to where to look. Generally it is the door gasket but not always. After this if it makes sense have somebody come out and access the damage.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We’re confident that its coming from the bottom left side of the dishwasher. When pressed, it seems to gush with water when the washer is running.

Comment: The problem here is that leaks frequently drip and run along something else by gravity or capillary action, and the water ends up some distance away from the leak.  I like to tie a length of TP along hoses and around joints/fittings, to home in on the actual location.

Answer (score 0):

That depends if your Insurance covers appliances.

Since you already know where is it leaking open the dishwasher and find and repair that.

As for the floor damage, who knows. Open it to find out.